# AWS Kinesis Client Java: Setting up TRIM_HORIZON Position in Stream does not work

Tags: java, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-client

I am running a test system that spawns a Kinesis producer which starts writing messages, e.g.: 1 through 100 to a stream with two shards.

During that cycle a consumer starts to read the messages from the stream. I noticed that the consumer only reads the `LATEST` messages that come into the stream after it's running. So for example, it starts reading at message 43. I tried modifying the Worker.class to use the `TRIM_HORIZON` Policy but this doesn't seem to be working.

```
KinesisClientLibConfiguration c = new KinesisClientLibConfiguration("MediaPlan", "randeepstream",
    DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance(),
    "consumer1")
    .withInitialPositionInStream(InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON);
final Worker w = new Worker.Builder()
    .recordProcessorFactory(rpf)
    .config(kinesisConfig)
    .build();
new Thread(() -> w.run()).start();
```

My consumer's processor is setup as:

```
public class ConsumerRecordProcessorImpl implements IRecordProcessor {

    public void initialize(InitializationInput initializationInput) {
        log.info("Setting up consumer with shard {} starting at {}", initializationInput.getShardId(),
                initializationInput.getExtendedSequenceNumber());
    }

    public void processRecords(ProcessRecordsInput processRecordsInput) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would expect to see a message like: 
`Setting up consumer with shard shardId-000000000000 starting at TRIM_HORIZON 0`
but instead I get:
`Setting up consumer with shard shardId-000000000000 starting at LATEST 0`

How do I get my consumer to stop reading the latest and read all unprocessed messages?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using amazon-kinesis-client lib v2.

You will have to use Schedular(software.amazon.kinesis.coordinator) which reads record in background  and provide a retrieval config to this scheduler as follows

```
RetrievalConfig retrievalConfig = setRetrievalConfig();

Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler(
        configsBuilder.checkpointConfig(),
        configsBuilder.coordinatorConfig(),
        configsBuilder.leaseManagementConfig(),
        configsBuilder.lifecycleConfig(),
        configsBuilder.metricsConfig(),
        configsBuilder.processorConfig(),
        retrievalConfig);

private RetrievalConfig setRetrievalConfig(){
    InitialPositionInStreamExtended initialPositionInStreamExtended = InitialPositionInStreamExtended.newInitialPosition(InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON);
    RetrievalConfig retrievalConfig = configsBuilder.retrievalConfig().retrievalSpecificConfig(new PollingConfig(streamName, kinesisClient));
    retrievalConfig.initialPositionInStreamExtended(initialPositionInStreamExtended);
    return retrievalConfig;
}
```

Notice the `InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON` this will tell the scheduler to start consume records after last known position. So even if the consumer is down and producer still running, all the records produces during downtime of the consumer will be consumed.

NOTE: configBuilder is object of ConfigsBuilder (software.amazon.kinesis.common)

UPDATE: initialPositionInStream position won't updated unless you call the checkpoint() API after processing the data you received from kinesis.
So once you call the checkpinter() then latest Position of the stream processing record gets updated in DynamoDB and now KCL will process the record from this position.

Comment: Important note: That setting (`InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON`) works only before the VERY first app start. At first start, It stored in the DynamoDB table and after that, always reads it from DynamoDB, completely ignoring the setting in code. To fix that, either remove the DynamoDB table (it will be created again with settings from code) either update the value of field `checkpoint` to `TRIM_HORIZON`

Comment: Its not for very first app start , its for EVERY RESTART .The TRIM (InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON )every restart the Stream Pressing will continue from last last position. If app is down for some time , then next processing will start from last checkpoint when app restarts  . You have to implement checkpoint call after successful processing of received kinesis record . 
This is mentioned in aws docs also : https://amzn.to/2VbVTr3
TRIM_HORIZON : Start streaming at the last untrimmed record in the shard, which is the oldest data record in the shard. 
For checkpointer call refer KCL

Comment: You missed an idea. Setting InitialPositionInStream is actually stored in the DynamoDB table, which you chose to hold lease owner information. If the table exists when your app is starting. InitialPositionInStream settings don't updated! I've spent almost an hour understanding this. I tried to change settings from LATEST to TRIM_HORIZONT in code, and the app didn't change it until I changed it in the table

Comment: You are absolutely correct @AlexeySviridov InitialPositionInStream is actually stored in the DynamoDB . InitialPositionInStream position don't updated unless you call the checkpoint() API after processing the data you received from kinesis.

So once you call the checkpinter() then latest Position of the stream processing record gets updated in DynamoDB and now KCL will process the record from this position. So even if your app is down you dont miss the data from Stream and continue processing from last chekpoint stored in DynmoDB.
I guess did not miss the point :)

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right now. The last comment makes things completely clear and correct.  So, maybe it's a good reason to update your answer? :)

Comment: `retrievalConfig.initialPositionInStreamExtended` is now deprecated, I haven't found a new way of getting the same behaviour

Comment: yes, this is deprecated. How do we achieve this now? @daker did you solve this?